# Read text file from server in Android app

Tags: java, android, file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

I want to open a text file (one line with a few words) from a server in a TextView, but my current code crashes the app when I open the activity. I've tried:

```
urlTextOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.URLtextView); 
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

try {
    String str = "";
    URL url = new URL("http://mysite.com/text1.txt");

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
         text.append(str);
    }
    in.close();
} catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
} catch (IOException e) {
}

urlTextOut.setText(text);
```

I've also tried something very similar to this: [How to read text file in android from web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099429/how-to-read-text-file-in-android-from-web) (with added try/catches where it wanted them) but that also crashed the app. I've tried looking at Apache's HttpComponents but couldn't figure out what I was meant to do with the downloaded zip file.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting a [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html). Android will not allow you to make network calls on the main/UI thread (ie directly in your Activity). You should use a separate thread, [see this question for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception).

Comment: Thanks, that is what's going wrong! I'm a bit confused about the AsyncTask class - it has a problem with the word RSSFeed in 'AsyncTask<String, Void, RSSFeed>' and 'protected RSSFeed doInBackground'. I tried changing the second to String since I'm using Strings not RSSFeeds, but it didn't help.