# Android read text file from internet

Tags: android, textview, text-files, httpurlconnection

I want to read a remote text file and show its content in a textview. I have written this below code, but it doesn't get any information from the text file. 
How can I find the reason of this problem or solve it?
isn't there anything wrong in my code?

```
    private void readFile()
    {
         try {
            String path ="http://host.com/info.txt";
            URL u = new URL(path);
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setDoOutput(true);
            c.connect();
            InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
            Log.e("value",in.toString());
            AssetManager mngr=getAssets();
            ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            in.read(buffer); // Read from Buffer.
            bo.write(buffer); // Write Into Buffer.
            TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
            text.setText(bo.toString());
            bo.close();
            }
         catch (NetworkOnMainThreadException e) {
        }
            catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Log.e("value",in.toString());  what it printing

Comment: this is incredibly unnecessary, just use WWW.  one line of code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Did you added internet permission to your Manifest file?
2. Are you launching your code in separate thread (please don't catch NetworkOnMainThreadException)
3. Check LogCat what exception do you have?
4. Removed `c.setDoOutput(true);` this is used to send data to server.

Here how it should be:

```
new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String path ="http://host.com/info.txt";
                URL u = null;
                try {
                    u = new URL(path);
                    HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
                    c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    c.connect();
                    InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
                    final ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    in.read(buffer); // Read from Buffer.
                    bo.write(buffer); // Write Into Buffer.

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
                            text.setText(bo.toString());
                            try {
                                bo.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }.start();
```

Comment: @DmytroDanylyk I tried this and it works well but the text gets cut off. (meaning i don't get all of the characters from the text file). I assumed that this was because of the size of the byte array but changing it did nothing. I also changed values of maxLength and lines for the textView but it did not help. Any ideas?

Comment: @sboehnke just use sample which read line by line, here http://stackoverflow.com/a/2468340/1056263