# How do I make a file open directly in the app?

Tags: android, eclipse, file, hyperlink, download

In my android app(using Eclipse), I have a link where the user clicks on and it downloads a word document. Instead I want it so when the user clicks on the link, it displays the word file(text) on the application it self. Please help! THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the word document is online, you first need to add internet permission to your Manifest file.

After that, you can use `HttpURLConnection` to get the file. Then, use `InputStream` to read the file, and `ByteArrayOutputStream` to write the file to your textview.

Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17141903/4195406

Comment: Well, yes the word document is online. I am using web view to display the website which has all my documents. So so far in my app, a user clicks on a button which then takes them to a new screen where it shows my website with all my document links. Although, when they click on the doucment it downloads it, so instead i want it so when they click on it, it just views in the app. Could you give me source code example? please and thank you!

Comment: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/04/read-text-file-from-internet-using-java.html This one should be a good example.