# How can I load an online text file's contents into a string with Android Studio in Kotlin?

Tags: android, string, kotlin, text

I copied over some Java code and had it converted to Kotlin code. It compiles and runs, but it is unable to load online text and set that text to a textview. I get a lot of permission denied statements when checking on the status of the app while it is running.

```
package com.example.app

import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import java.net.URLConnection
import java.net.URL
import java.util.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        var textBody: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textBody)

        var content: String? = null
        var connection: URLConnection? = null
        try {
            connection = URL("https://example.com").openConnection()
            val scanner = Scanner(connection.getInputStream())
            content = scanner.next()
            scanner.close()
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            ex.printStackTrace()
        }
       textBody.setText(content)


    }
}
```

Comment: That code is fairly ancient and was not designed with Android in mind. You might want to focus on newer educational resources. FWIW, [all my books are free now](https://commonsware.com/catalog), and they cover basic Android app development in Kotlin. This includes how to load content from Web servers.

Comment: check out this solution might help full  https://stackoverflow.com/a/17141903/7706832